# Can I store clicks for posts in WordPress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm curious if there's a way to track every click associated with a post in WordPress?  I know I can track views: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Maybe using Ajax?

Comment: Clicks on the actual links in the post content, or ?

Comment: No, the main permalink that takes you to the single post page.  I don't want to track single post page views, I want to track how many times someone clicks that link.

Comment: You could fairly easily track every link clicked on your site, is that what you are trying to do?  If not, please post a use-case so we can understand exactly what you're trying to do.